# How to correctly handle two different versions running commands from Terminal?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I've download `ctags` from Homebrew, which was installed in `/usr/local/bin/ctags`. Currently I have an older version of 'ctags' which is located in `/usr/bin/ctags/`.

I want the new version to be the default when executing `ctags` via the Terminal.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is to make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in your $PATH variable.

Comment: what is the safest way to change the $PATH variable?

Comment: It should be set in your shell config file (.profile, .bashrc for bash, .zshrc or .zshenv for zsh, etc...) You probably just need to rearrange the order of the folders. Assuming bash: look for a line that starts "export PATH=…" The delimiter between the folder names is a colon.

Comment: You don't want ctags as part of that path, just `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: You need to open a new shell window to execute the changes to ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: That should work.

Comment: Thanks, worked, just needed to quit the terminal and open it again. :-)

Comment: You can also use the 'source' command, but that won't always work because the paths get added dumbly and you get duplication.